# guild.createChannel wont work and i have no idea why

Tags: discord.js

I have been trying for a while now and i just can't figure this one out. So what I'm trying to do is use the bot to make a channel so that a person can open a ticket basically where only the user and a certain role are allowed to view and write in it. I haven't done the second part but this is bad enough.

Here's my pitiful attempt:

```
         case 'report':
            guild.createChannel('ticket-' + makeid, {
                type: 'text',
                permissionOverwrites: [{
                    id: guild.id,
                    deny: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
                }]
            })
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
            break;
```

In this case, **makeid** is a random string that's generated by a function.
error is:

```
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variable `guild`. There are multiple ways to do this in `Discord.js`, so here they are:

Using a user message:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
  let guild = message.guild;  //Get guild from the message
});
```

Or by using the GuildID:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  let guild = client.guilds.get("GUILD-ID");  //Replace "GUILD-ID" with the id of the guild you want
});
```

Comment: So if I use this it will automatically get the guildID ? The first method

Comment: The first one will retrieve the guild from the message, but **not** the guildID. To get the ID you can call `guild.id` (Which you already have in your code)